# textbox.visible is not set to true in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
bool bool_pre = true;
this.txtOperacionales.Visible = bool_pre;
```

Visible property can not be set to true and the control can not be displayed.

[the error can be seen also in step by step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0oQj.png)

[this is the aspx section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQdFD.png)

Comment: @OP - what do you mean by `Visible` property cannot be set to true? `Visible` is a read/write property. Are you setting it in an event handler? Is the line of code actually being executed? We need a little more to go on here.

Comment: the line is within a method I call to initialize the controls, this method is called in the Page_Load event in the condition !IsPostBack I using UpdatePanel, some controls are not I set others if the environment is Visual Studio 2010 framework 4 I realize step by step, we see that is not established.

Comment: Post the entirety of that method at the very least. Also include the lines in `Page_Load` that call it along with any conditions that it's enclosed by.

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object o, EventArgs e)
{
 if(!Page.IsPostBack)
  CargarControles(Type Args);
}

private void CargarControles(Args)
{ 
 string tipop;
 string compania;
 .
 .
 InicializaJuridica(tipop,compania);
 .
 .
}

private void InicializaJuridica(string tipop, string compania)
{
 bool bool_pre = true;
 this.txtOperacionales.Visible = bool_pre;
} is the sumary

Answer (score 0):

From reading the documentation on Visible, I think you have a parent control set to not visible.

> If a container control is not rendered, any controls that it contains
>   will not be rendered even if you set the Visible property of an
>   individual control to true. In that case, the individual control
>   returns false for the Visible property even if you have explicitly set
>   it to true. (That is, if the Visible property of the parent control is
>   set to false, the child control inherits that setting and the setting
>   takes precedence over any local setting.)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I can show an adjoining label and set the Text property and visibility, but do not understand why I can not set the visibility of this textbox

Comment: I've solved, it is because a label was blocking visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved, it is because a label was blocking visibility control